# Scala: Metaobject for traits

Tags: scala, metaprogramming

In Scala, there are metaobjects like `java.lang.Class` and `java.lang.reflect.Method`. But what metaobject exists for traits?

```
class Foo {
  def foo = "foo"
}

var obj = classOf[Foo]

obj // java.lang.Class[Foo] = interface Foo
```

It prints interface. What is this?

Comment: Err... scala 2.8.0.final prints java.lang.Class[Foo] = class Foo

Answer (score 6):

The output above comes as a surprise to me - it should print a class. Unless you wanted to declare `trait Foo`. What Scala version are you using?

The nightly gives the following as the output:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.0.r23117-b20100929093241 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM, Java 1.6.0_20).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class Foo {
     | def foo = "foo"
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> var obj = classOf[Foo]
obj: java.lang.Class[Foo] = class Foo
```

In the Scala JVM implementation Scala classes are usually translated into a JVM bytecode class. If a trait consists only of method declarations like here:

```
trait Foo {
  def foo: String
}
```

a Java interface `Foo` is generated by the compiler.

If it has definitions as well, like here:

```
trait Foo {
  def foo = "foo"
}
```

the compiler will generate an interface `Foo` and a so-called implementation class with the name `Foo$class` which contains the actual method bodies. This implementation class is not visible to the programmer. It is used for mixin-composition under the hood.

In both cases, if you use `classOf` construct to obtain the Class object of a trait, you will get the standard Java class object for the interface of the trait `Foo`, which you can use to inspect the methods of `Foo` in the same way as you would do it for classes.

Comment: Foo$class is actually attainable through some trickery like:

classOf[Foo].getClassLoader.getClass("Foo$class").   But in general the answer is spot on.

Comment: Nice, haven't thought about that.